# IFileStore mkdir

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I use make directory in

> IFileStore targetfileParent =
>   targetfileLocation.getParent().mkdir(EFS.SHALLOW, new
>   SubProgressMonitor(monitor, 0));

But I test it with

> if(!targetfileLocation.getParent().fetchInfo().exists()){ }

It returns true that means it cannot found the parent folder, which created by targetfileLocation.getParent().mkdir. Whereas, i could find the folder is successfully created during debugging.

```
void processContainer(IContainer container,IProject targetProject,IProgressMonitor monitor)     {
       try {
           IResource[] members = container.members();
           for (IResource member : members)
           {
              if (member instanceof IContainer) 
              {
                  processContainer((IContainer)member,targetProject,monitor);
              }
              else if (member instanceof IFile)
              { 
                  IFile memberfile = (IFile)member;

                  IPath relativefilePath = memberfile.getProjectRelativePath();
                  String fileName = relativefilePath.toOSString();
                  if(fileName.endsWith(".java.color")||fileName.endsWith(".color")){
                        continue;
                  }

                  IResource resouce  = targetProject.findMember(relativefilePath);
                  if(resouce==null){
                      IFile targetfile = targetProject.getFile(relativefilePath);

                      IFileStore sourcefileLocation = EFS.getLocalFileSystem().getStore(memberfile.getFullPath());

                      if(memberfile.exists()){
                          if(!targetfile.exists()){
                              IFileStore targetfileLocation = EFS.getLocalFileSystem().getStore(workspaceRoot.append(targetProject.getFullPath()).append(relativefilePath));
                              if(!targetfileLocation.getParent().fetchInfo().exists()){
                                  IFileStore targetfileParent = targetfileLocation.getParent().mkdir(EFS.SHALLOW, new SubProgressMonitor(monitor, 0));
                                  if(!targetfileLocation.getParent().fetchInfo().exists()){
                                      System.out.println("Not exist");
                                  }

                              }
                              System.out.println("Copy to distance:"+targetProject.getFullPath().append(relativefilePath).toOSString());
                              memberfile.copy(targetProject.getFullPath().append(relativefilePath), EFS.SHALLOW, new SubProgressMonitor(monitor, 0));
                          }
                      }

                 }
              }
           }        } catch (CoreException e) {             // TODO Auto-generated catch block          e.printStackTrace();        }

            }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using `IFile.create` and `IFolder.create`?

Comment: why use IFile.create since my target is to copy all files in one project into an anther project? I think copy might be suitable.

Comment: What I mean is stick to using the `IResource`, `IFolder` and `IFile` APIs which are simpler to use.